# Apparently this code erases all the files on Mac rather than just Duplicate code. I am unable to find the error.

Tags: macos, python-3.x, hash

```
import os,sys
import hashlib

path = '/Users'
unique = []
count = 0
mem = 0
statinfo=0

def fun(path):
    try:
        dirs = os.listdir(path)

        for x in dirs:
            print(path+'/'+x)

            statinfo = 0
            if os.path.isdir(path+'/'+x):
                fun(path+'/'+x)
            elif os.path.isfile(path+'/'+x):
                hasher = hashlib.md5()
                with open(path+'/'+x,'rb') as afile:
                    buf = afile.read()
                    hasher.update(buf)
                if hasher.hexdigest() not in unique:
                    unique.append(hasher.hexdigest())
                else:
                    statinfo=os.stat(path+'/'+x)
                    global mem
                    mem+=statinfo.st_size
                    os.remove(path+'/'+x)
                    global count
                    count+=1
        return
    except:
        pass

fun(path)
```

So this code apparently deleted all the files on my Macbook(Luckily, I took the backup before running the code). I ran this code from the terminal giving the sudo permission. To take care of permission error causing at Dropbox folder, I used Try and Except for error handling. I am unable to find what went wrong in the code.

Comment: Have you considered giving it a single test directory to run on and trying some debugging? Starting it on `/Users` probably wasn't the best idea...

Comment: Before running on /Users, I tried on a single folder by changing the path name. That worked perfect. But when I ran it on /Users, this happened.

Answer (score 0):

#### Analyse

You have a recursive call for each folders from the `/Users` path.

For each file, you calculate the md5 sum

- If the md5 don't already exist: you store it in a list,
- Else, you remove the file.

But, if you have an exception, for instance "Permission denied", you exit the function (some files / directory are lost).

Your code is not very secured:

- md5 sum is not enough to check duplicates, for instance: empty files are all duplicates. You can use `filecmp` to compare files.
- You analyse all directories even hidden one.
- What's about symbolic links?

#### Suggestion

However, you can try something more understandable:

```
import hashlib
import os


# Note that sometimes you won't be able to fit the whole file in memory.
# In that case, you'll have to read chunks of 4096 bytes sequentially
# and feed them to the Md5 function:
def md5(fname):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()


def find_duplicates(work_dir):
    found = {}
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(work_dir):
        for filename in filenames:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            try:
                hexdigest = md5(file_path)
                if hexdigest in found:
                    print("Duplicate of: " + found[hexdigest])
                    yield file_path
                else:
                    found[hexdigest] = file_path
            except IOError as exc:
                print(exc)


def remove_duplicates(path):
    for file_path in find_duplicates(path):
        print("remove: " + file_path)
        os.remove(file_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove_duplicates('/Users')
```

Comment: "But, if you have an exception, for instance "Permission denied", you exit the function (some files / directory are lost)."

But how? Wont the file be skipped whenever error occurs?

Comment: In your code, you process each file of each directory. If an error occurs on one file it is skipped, and the remaining files of the directory too. This is what I mean by "lost".